# Floating point arithmetic: Can these field axioms be satisfied?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

I am doing research on floating point arithmetic.

Suppose the usual arithmetic operations on a floating point system F(β, p, emin, emax, denorm) are written with
⊕, ⊖, ⊗, ⨸ (I am not sure if this symbol is right, it should be the `/` inside a circle), while usual functions are written SIN, COS, EXP, LN, SQRT, etc.

(F, ⊕, ⊗) is not a field because in general

(x ⊕ y ) ⊕ z ≠ x ⊕ (y ⊕ z)

(x ⊗ y ) ⊗ z ≠ x ⊗ (y ⊗ z)

(x ⊕ y ) ⊗ z ≠ x ⊗ z ⊕ y ⊗ z.

This is my first question on this site, so please guide me if I did something wrong.

However, my real question is this: I know that everywhere there are exceptions and this is the case as well. Are there (x,y,z) that actually satisfy the 3 equalities WITHOUT overflow or underflow?

Comment: @grand_chat, thank you for edit. Do you have any idea on how to determine the x,y,z if there are any?

Comment: You should check the IEEE standard for the rules, as this is what (most) modern hardware follows. The classic flaw is to keep adding floating point 1.0 to a sum, but once the value exceeds the basic size, the contribution is zero - so the sum never grows; I don't know if there is an exception for this today.  You might obtain a better response in one of the computer science forums.  To get started with the IEEE standard, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: all small integers will work. I believe some high level languages use double precision number to store integers.

Comment: @SimplyMe I am not familiar with floating point arithmetic. Are you looking for a single triplet of x,y,z? Do you need an example for any $\beta$? x=0 works, but this is a trivial case. Perhaps consider the case where x,y,z are small integers or small powers of $\beta$.

Comment: @PeterDiehr, that might get to an overflow where the a |x| > β × β^
emax

Comment: @achillehui, something like x=1, y=1, z=0?

Comment: @grand_chat, yes, I am interested in one or 2 examples of (x,y,z) where they actually satisfy the axiom.

Comment: @achillehui, now I see what you mean. x = 0 gets to the y +z = y + z and no matter what number I take, it's ok? For example, if I have β = 2 (binary). Can I take x = 0, y = 11 z = 11? I am not sure whether or not I got this right.

Comment: @SimplyMe IEEE doubles has $p = 53$ bit of accuracy. For any triplet of integers $(x,y,z)$ with $|x|,|y|,|z| < 2^{\lfloor (p-1)/2 \rfloor} = 2^{26}$, they satisfy the 3 axioms (b/c all intermediate and final pieces are representable).

Comment: Ooooh, so that is the actual way for it. Basically no matter what numbers I take, simple or double precision, as long as they are internally representable, they need no aproximation and will satisfy the inequation?
And even x=0, y=1, z=110 will be good, since z=2^2+2^1=5 < 2^26. Did I get it right?

Comment: @SimplyMe, essentially yes. The IEEE specification demands for addition, subtraction and multiplication, the result will be the exact result rounded to representable number following certain rule (there are multiple rules one can choose). In the case the exact result is representable, it will be the answer returned.

Comment: @achillehui, so to sum it up, x=0, y=1, z=110 in β=2 are a viable example?

Comment: @SimplyMe, yup!

Comment: @achillehui, I have one single question left. IF I delete this question, can I undelete it in 1 week?

Comment: @SimplyMe I think so but I've never posted nor delete (my own) question before. BTW, make sure you keep a link for this, once a question/answer is deleted from SE, it is usually hard to locate it w/o a link.